# Error getting authentication to Azure data factory

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, azure-data-factory

I need to hit the data factory pipeline with the REST call ...
So, I

1. Registered application in the Azure Active Directory.
2. Obtained Client_ID and client_Secret

Then I try to use Postman to get the authentication token and get an error, which I do not understand.  Please, help.  How can I get authentication token to my ADF using Postman ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In body section, instead of `raw`, use - `x-www-form-urlencoded` as below and it should help resolve the issue.

[image]

Ideally, when you select `x-www-form-urlencoded` radio button in the `Body` section, it automatically sets the `Content-Type`=`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` under the Headers tab as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  !! It worked.  I am able to get a bearer token.
The now issue is .. when hitting the data factory pipelkine with the REST call having this token, I get "Authentication Failed" ... but it maybe another issue ...

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow below steps for generating bearer token In ADF :**

**Step 1:** Create  a web activity to get the Access Token from ADF.

**URL:** `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant ID>/oauth2/token`

[image]

- **Method :** POST
- **Body:** `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&resource=https://management.azure.com/`
- **Header:** `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image]

**Step2:** Create Set variable :

- Add dynamic content ->  `@activity('Web1').output.access_token`

[image]

**Pipeline successfully executed and got the token**

[image]